# How do I make a <div> link in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

How do I make an entire div as a link in Laravel?

(using `{{ link_to() }}` does not work for me because I want an entire div to be clickable)

In traditional HTML I would link a div like the following

```
<a href="page.php">
    <div>
        ....
    </div>
</a>
```

How would I do this in Laravel? Assuming I want to link to `page.blade.php` and the route set up for `page.blade.php` is

```
Route::get('/page', function(){
    return View::make('page');
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with HTML::decode

```
{{ HTML::decode(link_to('page','<div>....</div>')) }}
```

Comment: I get FatalErrorException (E_PARSE) 
syntax error, unexpected '__data' (T_STRING)

Any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 4):

You can let Laravel generate the URL and write the rest of the HTML yourself

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('page') }}">
    <div></div>
</a>
```